# Does $f^{-1}(Y)$ make sense if $Y$ is "bigger" than $X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My textbook asks me to decide whether or not this expression is true:

> Given the function $f: X \to Y$ with $B_1 \subseteq Y $.
>   $ f^{-1}(Y $ \ $ B_1) = X $ \ $f^{-1}(B_1) $

I was confused because there is no assumption that the function $f$ is *onto*. Hence there might be an element $y \in Y$ such that for no $x \in X$, $f(x) = y$. I actually don't know if in this case the expression $f^{-1}(Y)$ makes sense.

Comment: By definition, $f^{-1}(Y)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in Y\}=X$.

Answer (score 2):

**One Interpretation (probably wrong):**

If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and you assume that   $f^{-1}$ exists as a mapping at element level from $Y \rightarrow X$, then $f$ must be not only surjective but also injective. From that you can then show $f^{-1}(Y \setminus B_1) = X \setminus f^{-1}(B_1)$.

**Another Interpretation (probably correct):**

Using the suggested notataion in comments, $f^{-1} [B_1] = \{x \in X\colon f(x) \in B_1\}$ and $f^{-1} [Y] = \{x \in X\colon f(x) \in Y\}= X$ (assuming that $f$ is follows the normal definition of a fucntion from $X$).

$$\begin{align} 
f^{-1} [Y \setminus  B_1] &=  \{ x \in X\colon f(x) \in Y  \setminus  B_1\}\\
&=\{ x \in X\colon f(x) \in Y  \land f(x) \notin B_1\}\\
&= \{  x \in X\colon x \in X \land x \notin f^{-1} [B_1]\}\\
&= X  \setminus f^{-1} [B_1].
\end{align}$$

Comment: You're misinterpreting the symbol $f^{-1}(B)$ where $B\subseteq Y$. Admittedly, the notation is ambiguous. By definition  $f^{-1}(B)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in B\}$. You shouldn't look at $f^{-1}(B)$ as the preimage of the inverse of $f$, but rather as string of symbols which happens to have the symbol $f^{-1}$ in it. Personally I prefer the notation $f^{-1}[B]$.

Comment: @Git Gud - I learn't something there.

Comment: @GitGud My preference goes to $f^\gets$ (inverse image) and $f^\to$ (direct image).

Comment: @egreg It's a nice notation. I've never seen it before.

Comment: @GitGud Probably somebody would use $f_\to$ (it's applying a covariant functor). A teacher of mine used these arrows, I don't remember who. In any case, I find $f^{-1}(B)$ very confusing for the students. Using $[]$ around the set helps, though, provided one has talked about relations and sections.

Comment: @egreg Can you please enlighten me on  *Sections ?* I tried a quick Google on "sets relations sections" without anything leaping out at me.

Comment: @TomCollinge If $R\subseteq X\times Y$, and $A\subseteq X$, you can define $R[A]=\{y\in Y: (x,y)\in R\text{ for some }x\in A\}$. Whether $R[A]$ is called a *section* depends on local conventions. Note that $R^{-1}[B]$, for $B\subseteq Y$, doesn't need a definition. In the case $R=f$ is a function $X\to Y$, $f^{-1}[B]$ is exactly the inverse image.