# Is $\mathbb R^3 $ subspace of $\mathbb R^4 $

Tags: linear-algebra

I think $\mathbb R^3 \not\subseteq \mathbb R^4$ since $\mathbb R^4$ contains no ordered triples. So, $\mathbb R^3$ is not a suspace of $\mathbb R^4$. Does that make sense?

Comment: It is isomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$, namely the subspace with one of the coordinates fixed at 0. This is usually what people mean when they say it is a subspace.

Comment: See number 14 http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1024302/137487

Comment: To elaborate on other comments, you are correct when you say $\mathbb{R}^3 \nsubseteq \mathbb{R}^4$ as *sets*, since $\mathbb{R}^4$ does not contain any triples. However, there is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ (see @ChristopherHalverson's response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. However, $\mathbf{R}^4$ contains subspaces which are *isomorphic* to $\mathbf{R}^3$.