# Notation to mark which variables a function is dependent of?

Tags: functions, notation

If I have a function $f$, how do I mark the variables of a function, without going through the hassle of formally constructing it like this;

> $$\begin{array}{l}f:&A\to B\\&\color{green}{(x_1;x_2;...;x_n)} \mapsto f(x_1;x_2;...;x_n) \end{array}$$

If I have the relation $y = x^2+cz+b$, and want to mark that $y$ is a function of $x$, how can I mark this? Apparently $y(x)$ is a value, so that won't do the trick, and $y_x$ is a partial derivative, so I don't see any nice shorthand way of marking it.

Comment: $y(x)$ is the standard way to mark a dependence of $y$ on $x$ explicitly.

Comment: $y(x)$ is a value, but I guess you can easily write down $y(x)=x^2+cz+b$ meaning the $y$ depends on $x$, also, I think I have seen the following somewhere: $y(x\_)=x^2+cz+b$, if you had more than one, you'd write $y(x\_,z\_,w\_)$ for example

Comment: I think there's no standard way to do this. You have to tell from context each time. Some of the popular answers to your popular question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024280/most-ambiguous-and-inconsistent-phrases-and-notations-in-maths address this very point.

Comment: What is wrong with : $y=f(x)$ ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Nothing wrong, but that implicitly defines the variable. I'd find it better with an explicit marking.

Comment: See the related post : [when did the abuse of notation $y=y(x)$ start ?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/252928/when-did-the-abuse-of-notation-y-yx-start).