# Supremum of $\sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Find the supremum of

$$\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} $$

where $n$ is in the set of natural numbers.
It's a silly question I am stuck at.
Is the answer $1$ or is it $\sqrt{2} -1$?
There's a bit of confusion. Please help out.

Comment: is it $\sqrt{n+1-\sqrt{n}}$ or $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: Is $0$ a natural number or not?

Comment: @VIVID It looks like $\sqrt{n}+1-\sqrt{n}=1$, but, well, ...then the answer would be $1$ at least.

Comment: Error in the title, different error in the question, and error when you say that $n$ is a set. Make an effort, Shatabdi! But there is certainly confusion about what "natural number" means $-$ does it include $0$ or not? (See [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1029623/1508)). If the question doesn't specify either way, then it is flawed.

Comment: @TonyK: But, in axiomatic set theory, natural numbers *are* sets!

Comment: @Bernard: Very clever. But $n$ is _not_ the set of natural numbers.

Comment: Certainly– $\mathbf N$ is the union of all finite ordinals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}
=\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right) \frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} = f(n)$$
Since $f$ is decreasing, the supremum is $f(0)=1$ if $0 \in \mathbb N$ and $f(1)= \sqrt 2 - 1$ if $0 \notin \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

This sequence is strict descenting sequence so then if you are dealing with natural numbers the maximum or supremum of this sequence are the same and happens when $n = 1$ and equals to $\sqrt 2 - 1$.