# If $x+xy+y=55$, what is $x+y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x,y\in \mathbb N$ is s.t. $$x+xy+y=55,$$
find $x+y$ ?

---

I tried to write $x+xy+y=65$ as an equation of $x+y$, but can't go anywhare :

1. Using the fact that $$xy=\frac{1}{4}((x+y)^2-(x-y)^2,$$
   I have that $$x+xy+y=55\iff (x+y)+\frac{1}{4}(x+y)^2-\frac{1}{4}(x-y)^2=65,$$

but I just transposed the problem with $x-y$.

Other things I tried is to replace $xy$ by $$\frac{1}{2}((x+y)^2-x^2-y^2)$$
but still, I can't do anything with $x^2+y^2$.

any idea ?

Comment: @Surb, gotta add $1$ to get that factorization. So, it's divisors of $56$ you want.

Comment: @joshua FYI, please see [Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Simon%27s_Favorite_Factoring_Trick).

Comment: There are several solutions (three, in fact). For example, $(x,y)=(6,7)$ or $(13,3)$. Can you find the third, using the hints in these comments?

Comment: joshua, what do you mean when you write $\Bbb N$ ? Do you refer to positive integers or nonnegative integers?

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I am going to assume that $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$ since @joshua did not specify.*

$x+xy+y=55 \implies x+xy+y+1=(x+1)(y+1)=56$

Since $x, y\in\mathbb{N}$, $x+1, y+1\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

Listing out all the cases, we get that
$$\begin{align*}
x+y&=0+55=55 \text{ or}\\
&=1+27=28 \text{ or}\\
&=3+13=16 \text{ or}\\
&=6+7=13
\end{align*}$$

Hence, $\boxed{x+y=55, 28, 16 \text{ or } 13}$.

Comment: $x=0$ is wrong as $x\in\mathbb{N}.$ Other than that, good solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Since the OP did not state exactly what he means by the symbol** $\,\Bbb N\,$ **(positive integers or nonnegative integers), in my answer I am assuming that** $\,x\,$ **and** $\,y\,$ **are nonnegative integers**.

As Gerry pointed out, $\,x+xy+y=55\,,\,$ is equivalent to
$\color{blue}{x+1}+\color{red}{xy+y}=56\quad$ which is equivalent to
$\color{blue}{1(x+1)}+\color{red}{y(x+1)}=56\quad$ which is equivalent to
$(x+1)(1+y)=56\quad$ which is equivalent to
$(x+1)(y+1)=56\,,\quad$ consequently,

$x+1=1\quad$ and $\quad y+1=56$

or

$x+1=2\quad$ and $\quad y+1=28$

or

$x+1=4\quad$ and $\quad y+1=14$

or

$x+1=7\quad$ and $\quad y+1=8$

or

$x+1=8\quad$ and $\quad y+1=7$

or

$x+1=14\quad$ and $\quad y+1=4$

or

$x+1=28\quad$ and $\quad y+1=2$

or

$x+1=56\quad$ and $\quad y+1=1$

Hence,

$x+y\in\big\{55,28,16,13\big\}\,.$

**In the case that the OP refers to** $\,\Bbb N\,$ **as the set of all positive integers, it results that**, $\,x+y\neq55\,,\,$ **consequently**,

$x+y\in\big\{28,16,13\big\}\,.$

Comment: Whether $(x,y)=(55,0)$ is a solution depends on your [definition of $\Bbb N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1029623/1508). To make this a well-posed question, you should stipluate $x,y\in\Bbb N_{>0}$ or $x,y\in\Bbb N_{\ge 0}$.

Comment: @TonyK, if you read the beginning of my answer, I wrote that I am assuming that $x$ and $y$ are **nonnegative** integers.

Comment: There's no need for a definition....$\mathbb{N}$ means natural numbers and they start from $1$

Comment: Does this really matter so much? If OP doesn't want 0 in $\mathbb N$, they can just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

$x+y+xy=55$

$x+y+xy+1=56$

$(x+1)(y+1)=56$

$56=1×56=2×28=4×14=7×8=8×7=4×14=28×2=56×1$

Possible values of $(x,y)$ and $x+y:$

- $(0,55), 55$
- $(1,27), 28$
- $(3,13), 16$
- $(6,7), 13$
- $(7,6), 13$
- $(13,3), 16$
- $(27,1), 28$
- $(55,0) , 55.$

We find four unique values for the sum:
$$x+y=13\text{ or }16\text{ or }28\text{ or }55.$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community: it was not unclear at all. It only needed some formatting. Please ziansarisha, next time [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).